# Getting Was expecting: <NAME> ... when importing java file in jython

Tags: java, jython

I am quite new to jython. And in my project there is an existing jython file.
This jython file is referring to few java classes present in custom jar.

Here are the import statements

```
from oracle.ess import PrintVersion
from oracle.as.scheduler import CalendarWrapper
```

first import statement is not giving any error

but second import statement is giving error under **as** which is part of package name saying **was expecting: NAME ...**

One more thing both import statement are part of same jar, so I can not think of any classpath related issues.

So I am feeling like as is not allowed word as part of java package name.

Is there some thing like not allowed words in java package name while using them in jython.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`as` is a keyword, check it with [`keyword.iskeyword(s)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/keyword.html#keyword.iskeyword):

```
import keyword

keyword.iskeyword('as')
```

This makes it impossible to import any module named `as`.

Comment: does it mean, i can not import because the java package name contains as

Comment: I am not sure, as this program runs well. Its like it runs with in an environment properly but to debug i just took this one python class and added it in a pydev project in eclipse.